# Laravel Simple Authorization - Sometimes not working - "Invalid credentials."

Tags: php, laravel

I use "HTTP Basic Authentication" for my administration in Laravel 5.4

It is working correctly, but sometimes it shows "Invalid credentials." and I cannot login (the HTTP Basic Auth doesn't pop up).

I suspect that Chrome is sending some credentials it already stored and Laravel doesn't pair it and instead of showing another Auth pop up, it just dies with the text "Invalid credentials."

I tried erasing all cookies, caches, everything except "passwords" (don't want to lose them), and it still isn't showing Simple Auth popup to ask my credentials.

I have tried opening the site in Chrome Ghost/Guest mode and it is working there (asks for auth and then logs in).

Can you help?

I set this up by putting 'middleware' => 'auth.basic' in ROUTES and then Auth::routes();
And then just added this line in /app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

**So basically I have zero customization...** just simple Auth addition.

---

## UPDATE #1:

I debugged this to file \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php

However even putting my own stuff:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm=test');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
exit;
```

Doesn't invoke the popup!!!
From what I've read it seems like some Chrome issue.
I tried all kinds of variations, but the popup still isn't coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically I called this address:
https://username:password@mysite.com/

**Important here is to use correct username and correct password!**

After that it began working again, so it was Chrome issue :)

Any other method including chrome://restart or erasing cache, cookies etc. didn't work.